# how to customize localhost of wamp server

Tags: wamp

I changed the port of my wamp server to 8080, because my IIS is using the port 80.

When I try running my HTML and PHP files using (eg: localhost:8080/filename) it doesn't load so is there a way to customize localhost of wamp server to a different name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using WAMPServer 3+ you can do this all from the wampmanager menus.

First undo the changes you made manually.

(right click)wampmanager->Tools->Use a port other than 80

Enter 8080 (or any port number) into the command windows

Let WAMPServer make all the correct amendments to httpd.conf and other files, it will then restart Apache for you to pick up these chnages.

Answer (score 0):

1. Configure iis running as service
2. Stop iis
3. Install wampserver (w/ option running as service)
4. Open httpd.conf in wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.9/conf
5. Find and change "listen 80" to other port such as 81, 8080, so on, to become "listen 81" or "listen 8080"
6. Enable associated port 81, 8080, so on for wampserver in all firewalls and routers
7. Restart your computer, and now you have both iis and wampserver running

Comment: You missed a couple of thing